# Ignore Press button

Tags: c#, while-loop, gdi+

I need call PaintEvent in `while(canDrawing)` loop. Where I need use loop?
In Event it can't stop drawing, `Esc` doesn't call.

```cs
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    penCircle = new Pen(BackColor, radius);
}

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brushPoint, RandomXPosition(), RandomYPosition(), 1, 1);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(penCircle, xPositionCircle, yPositionCircle, radius, radius);
}

private void Esc(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        canDrawing = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could of course fix it by calling [DoEvents()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5181777/1997232) in the loop, but... Rather than using tight loop inside paint event, consider to chain `Invalidate()` calls. Event handlers are not supposed to do constant job. Use task, thread, timer for this.

Comment: `Form1 form = new Form1();` inside paint event is really awkward.

Comment: heightOfForm = ClientSize.Height;
            widthOfForm = ClientSize.Width;
            colorOfCircle = BackColor;

Comment: tnx it`s similar

Comment: _graphics.Dispose();_ Do not dispose of things you didn't create! - _Form1 form = new Form1();_ This is a new form, not the one your are trying to paint on. - There is no escape from the loop; instead call Invalidate() to trigger the Paint event from an outside loop that also tests the keyboard state.

Comment: where need use loop?

Comment: The loop can be anywhere, e.g. in a void PaintLoop method. Just make sure it contains code to test the keyboard. As it is the loop is tight and will not allow anything else..

Comment: man TNX!, I wasted 3 hours.